# Insert webpage inside a .vsdx project

Tags: html, css, embed, dashboard, visio

I have to embed a dynamic dashboard (written using HTML/CSS/JS) created by myself inside a Visio Drawing (.vsdx) file.

I haven't find a way to do that. If it is not possible directly in Visio, can I embed that dashboard in Visio by using another Microsoft Office Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the content needs to stay dynamic. Insert Microsoft's Webbrowser control in the drawing. 
You may need some code to get it to navigate to your page.
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa752044(v=vs.85).aspx)